# Flutter: Syncfusion charts how to explicitly set number of x axis labels to show

Tags: flutter, charts, syncfusion, x-axis

I'm using [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts) to show charts in my app.

With my data, the x-axis is always a `DateTime`

All I want to do is explicitly set the x-axis labels to show and WHERE to show them if possible, e.g.

- Show 2 or 4 labels evenly spaced, beginning (so centred under the y-axis) and at end of the x-axis

Like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Here's what I have so far which doesn't quite work, but I'm not sure why:

```
    return DateTimeAxis(
      dateFormat: (showXAxisAsName) ? DateFormat("MMM") : DateFormat("dd/MM"),
      majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0),
      majorTickLines: MajorTickLines(width: 0),
      axisLine: AxisLine(
        width: 1,
        color: (axesColour != null) ? axesColour : GTColors.lightGrey,
      ),
      labelStyle: GTTextStyle.caption2.copyWith(
        color: (axesColour != null) ? axesColour : GTColors.lightGrey,
      ),
      minimum: (hasData) ? DateTime(first.year, first.month) : null,
      maximum: (hasData) ? DateTime(last.year, last.month) : null,
      intervalType: DateTimeIntervalType.months,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

We suggest you the axisLabelFormatter to customize the axis label style and text based on your requirement,if you want to show only the first and last label then you can return the empty string in this callback except for the first and last label. In another way you have to set the interval property in the axis it defines the interval between the data points, so set the interval value based on your requirement.

UG:

•   https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/callbacks#axislabelformatter

•   https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/axis-types#customizing-interval

Comment: How would I know whether it's the first or last? I don't see anything in the AxisLabelRenderDetails object that will tell me that.